# How to aggregate query results into camelCased json format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want a way to dynamically aggregate arbitrary query results in json format (with camelCase keys).

The jsonb_agg function is really close to what I want.

```
--Example table
create table test.foo(id int, some_col text, another_val date);
insert into test.foo(id, some_col, another_val)
values (1, 'Hello there', '2020-01-01'),
       (2, 'Bonjour', '1984-02-23');
--select
select jsonb_agg(f)
from test.foo f;
```

which returns

```
[{"id": 1, "some_col": "Hello there", "another_val": "2020-01-01"}, {"id": 2, "some_col": "Bonjour", "another_val": "1984-02-23"}]
```

This is almost what I want, but since our app expects camelCase keys, what I really need is this

```
[{"id": 1, "someCol": "Hello there", "anotherVal": "2020-01-01"}, {"id": 2, "someCol": "Bonjour", "anotherVal": "1984-02-23"}]
```

Ideally, I want a way to write this for virtually any select statement

```
select jsonb_agg_with_camel_keys(f)
from test.foo f;
-- or for functions
select jsonb_agg_with_camel_keys(f)
from test.some_function(param_one, param_two) f;
```

However, such a function does not exist that I am aware of.

For now, we are doing this

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(foos)))
from
    (
        select
            f.id          as id,
            f.some_col    as "someCol",
            f.another_val as "anotherVal"
        from
            test.foo f
    ) foos;
```

This works, but since we use this pattern regularly, it is tedious, error prone (typos), and takes more work to maintain than a generic solution would (especially when there are multiple nested levels of select statements).

**Ideally, the solution would automatically turn snake_case to camelCase for all keys (included multiple levels of nested json). The solution would be dynamic (accepting any input like the jsonb_agg function already does). The solution could be used for table and function results.
Note that only json keys need to be altered. All other output should remain unchanged.**

In theory, I could write some sort of regex_replace that replaces json keys after the aggregation is done. While certainly a possibility, it seems that it would be more efficient to do the conversion during the aggregation process.
I understand that postgresql expects well defined types, which makes writing a plpgsql function difficult. I have tried thinking of a way to do this, but doing it for function results would be difficult.
I also understand that one option is writing my own aggregate function in C, basically a variant of jsonb_agg (if this is the best option, then a general description of how to do so would be appreciated, since I have not done that before).

Thank you in advance for your time and thoughts.

EDIT

Renaming column names is not a good solution for me. It would require a major refactor and would be much more work and trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Rename all your columns with camel case then use `json_agg` and the output will be in camel case.